# Debugging AWS SAM / Lambda / TypeScript project with VS Code (source mapping config?)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, source-maps, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am having trouble debugging AWS SAM project with Lambda written in TypeScript using VS Code.

My project setup is as follows.

Project generated using `sam init` and `Hello World Example TypeScript` template:

```
>sam init

You can preselect a particular runtime or package type when using the `sam init` experience.
Call `sam init --help` to learn more.

Which template source would you like to use?
        1 - AWS Quick Start Templates
        2 - Custom Template Location
Choice: 1

Choose an AWS Quick Start application template
        1 - Hello World Example
        2 - Data processing
        3 - Hello World Example with Powertools for AWS Lambda
        4 - Multi-step workflow
        5 - Scheduled task
        6 - Standalone function
        7 - Serverless API
        8 - Infrastructure event management
        9 - Lambda Response Streaming
        10 - Serverless Connector Hello World Example
        11 - Multi-step workflow with Connectors
        12 - Full Stack
        13 - Lambda EFS example
        14 - Hello World Example With Powertools
        15 - DynamoDB Example
        16 - Machine Learning
Template: 1

Use the most popular runtime and package type? (Python and zip) [y/N]: n

Which runtime would you like to use?
        1 - aot.dotnet7 (provided.al2)
        2 - dotnet6
        3 - go1.x
        4 - go (provided.al2)
        5 - graalvm.java11 (provided.al2)
        6 - graalvm.java17 (provided.al2)
        7 - java17
        8 - java11
        9 - java8.al2
        10 - java8
        11 - nodejs18.x
        12 - nodejs16.x
        13 - nodejs14.x
        14 - python3.9
        15 - python3.8
        16 - python3.7
        17 - python3.11
        18 - python3.10
        19 - ruby3.2
        20 - ruby2.7
        21 - rust (provided.al2)
Runtime: 11

What package type would you like to use?
        1 - Zip
        2 - Image
Package type: 1

Based on your selections, the only dependency manager available is npm.
We will proceed copying the template using npm.

Select your starter template
        1 - Hello World Example
        2 - Hello World Example TypeScript
Template: 2

Would you like to enable X-Ray tracing on the function(s) in your application?  [y/N]: n

Would you like to enable monitoring using CloudWatch Application Insights?
For more info, please view https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-application-insights.html [y/N]: n

Project name [sam-app]: sam-ts-app

    -----------------------
    Generating application:
    -----------------------
    Name: sam-ts-app
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    Architectures: x86_64
    Dependency Manager: npm
    Application Template: hello-world-typescript
    Output Directory: .
    Configuration file: sam-ts-app\samconfig.toml

    Next steps can be found in the README file at sam-ts-app\README.md


Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Create pipeline: cd sam-ts-app && sam pipeline init --bootstrap
[*] Validate SAM template: cd sam-ts-app && sam validate
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: cd sam-ts-app && sam sync --stack-name {stack-name} --watch
```

... with the following generated `hello-world/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "strict": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "module":"es2015",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "esModuleInterop": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
  }
```

... and the following metadata in `template.yaml`:

```
...
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    ...
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints: 
        - app.ts
...
```

... then I am successfully building it using:

```
> sam build
```

After build, I am seeing source map file generated at `.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction\app.js.map`

I tried 2 ways of debugging this in VS Code.

[A] By attaching debugger to local invoke.

1. run `sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction -d 9999`
2. Attach from VS Code using the following run config inside `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
       {
            "name": "Attach to SAM CLI",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9999,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/hello-world",
            "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "stopOnEntry": false
        },
```

[B] By generating (using AWS Toolkit plugin) and running the following run config from `template.yaml`:

```
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "sam-ts-app:HelloWorldFunction",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        },
```

Both ways do execute lambda but fail to catch breakpoint inside VS Code and give the following in `DEBUG OUTPUT` window:

```
Could not read source map for file:///var/task/app.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Leo\workspace\sam-ts-code-test\sam-ts-app\hello-world\app.js.map'
```

It looks like a problem with VS Code not finding relevant source map file, but I am not sure how to solve this.

I tried to play with `tsconfig.json`, `template.yaml` and `sourceMapPathOverrides` inside run configuration (not even sure that I did this correctly), but can't find working way to glue this together.

PS: I am using:

- VS Code 1.81.0
- AWS Toolkit 1.82.0
- SAM CLI, version 1.94.0
- Full project code can be found [here](https://github.com/EugeneLoy/sam-ts-app)

Comment: Do you see a `sourceMappingURL` entry in your `.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction\app.js.map` file? Does the path match the actual location of the map file relative to app.js?

Comment: @VonC No, "sourceMappingURL" is not there. I've pushed content of the build, so you can check what is in there here: https://github.com/EugeneLoy/sam-ts-app/blob/master/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/app.js.map

Comment: The path specified in the `sources` property in the `app.js.map` file points to a temporary directory (`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Temp/tmpev4p181r/app.ts`), which does not really map to your actual TypeScript source code location. Can you try and replace the `sources` line with `"sources": ["app.ts"]`? Check if a debug session works better with that.

Comment: @VonC I tried putting both "app.ts", and "hello-world/app.ts" into "sources", but I am getting the same results.

Comment: Also tried copying (+ setting "sources" inside) map file from build to "hello-world" directory. Message about missing map file in debug console is now gone but I still cant catch breakpoint.

Comment: The inability to catch a breakpoint even after resolving the source map issues suggests there is still a mismatch between the generated JavaScript and the actual TypeScript source during the debugging process. Make sure the source maps are Loaded Properly: In your `.vscode/launch.json` for the "Attach to SAM CLI" configuration, try adding:
    ```json
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "/var/task/*": "${workspaceRoot}/hello-world/*"
    }
    ```
    That directive tells the debugger how to map the paths from the source maps to your local source code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254823/discussion-between-vonc-and-eugene-loy).